# Acer M5 481pt 6488 use of touchscreen stylus

Tags: touchscreen

I am wanting to do some basic drawing with Adobe Illustrator using a touchscreen stylus.  I was looking at an answer to a different question, and Ben Richards had made mention that laptops that support digitizer (possibly wrong terminology) technology is superior.  I tried a quick search to see if my model supports that, but I couldn't find anything.  How can I find out if my laptop supports this technology?  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

The odds are if it had a digitizer-type touchscreen it would have came with a very nice stylus, been in all the print material, and cost you more. ;)

Easiest/cheapest test: [Buy](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.Xcapacitive+stylus&_nkw=capacitive+stylus&_sacat=0&_from=R40) (or [make](http://www.labnol.org/gadgets/capacitive-stylus-pen-for-touch-screens/)) a cheap capacitive stylus made for the iPad and alike.  If it works, you don't have a digitizer.